# Merging PHP + Mysql website with joomla website

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, frontend

this may sound obvious, but i want to know what you think about this, because i may be looking for a bad approach to this, and there could be easier ways to do this.
So I'm used to code directly using php+mysql to develop websites and CMS without using any solutions like wordpress, joomla, drupal, etc.

Here's my problem:
I built one website, and what I have right now is mainly the administration area, but i need a supporting website, like a frontend(public website).
This website will basically display some of the queries that are already working on the administration area, and will contain basically the result of some queries that are already made.

So my question is this:

If i decide to use joomla (or other) for the public website (frontend) to display those queries is there an easier way to do this besides including the php file with the db connect and all the stuff that i'm used to work with? Or can use some module, or some way to include my query results on joomla webpages? (note that i will use a different database and not the joomla database, or if this is a problem I can merge both)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Once you switch to using a CMS like Joomla, you're either stuck using Joomla's functionality, or writing custom modules for Joomla to recreate your existing stuff within Joomla's bounds.

Comment: Thanks, that what I tought that would happen.  I guess there's no solution at all to simply create one webpage, use the same template that joomla uses and inside that page display a simple query result that worked normally on my php webpages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have pages that display your content, then you can just use Joomla's built in "wrapper" menu item to load those pages within the content area of Joomla.

Comment: Thank you very much, i'll try that, I used that a while back for HTML portions of code, but i never tested with php code, functions, etc.